# How to solve terrain map shortest path with dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

Given a matrix of all `positive` integers, starting from the left most column `0th`, find the minimum path to the right most column `(n - 1)th`. For example:
[image]

The minimum path is the path which contains on 1's.

At any given square `m[i, j]`, we can move to 4 directions (`left, right, up, down`); of course except all corner cases at left most, right most row/column. For example, at `[0, 0]`, we only can move `right` or `down`.
My solution is to build a graph of `m x n` vertices, then run **Floyd-Warshall** to compute all pair shortest path of any two vertices `(u, v)`. Then run another nested `for` loop to check all the vertices of the `0th` column with all vertices of the `(n - 1)th` column to find the minimum path.
However, my professor suggested another algorithm by using the following recurrence:

```
S[i, j, L] = 
    min(
        S[i - 1, j, L - 1] + cost[i - 1, j],
        S[i + 1, j, L - 1] + cost[i + 1, j],
        S[i, j - 1, L - 1] + cost[i, j - 1],
        S[i, j + 1, L - 1] + cost[i, j + 1]);
```

which I have no clue how it works! Since at any given square `[i, j]` we can move in 4 direction and this make it impossible to build a table based on previous pre-computed values.
Did I miss something here? I can't see how this recurrence work out. Any idea?

Comment: I think your professor forgot to mention that 1) S need not be computed (i.e. is infinite) past the edges of the matrix, and 2) S[0,0,0]=0.

Comment: ...P.S. I know this isn't what you're asking, but this really cries out for an iterative (non-recursive) BFS.

Comment: If you have `S[i,j,0] = infinity`, except for `S[0,0,0] = 0`, then it should work.  Eventually all S[i,j,k]==S[i,j,k+1] and you can stop iterating.  S[i,j,k] then has the cost of the shortest path from (0,0) to (i,j).

Comment: @VaughnCato: Could you elaborate it a bit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have S[i,j,0] = infinity, except for S[0,j,L] = 0, then it should work. Eventually all S[i,j,L]==S[i,j,L+1] and you can stop iterating. S[i,j,L] then has the cost of the shortest path from the first column to that cell.

This is how this recurrence would look in the upper-left corner for increasing values of L.

```
0   inf inf inf inf
0   inf inf inf inf
0   inf inf inf inf

0   1   inf inf inf inf
0   20  inf inf inf inf
0   21  inf inf inf inf

0   1   2   inf inf inf
0   2   30  inf inf inf
0   21  22  inf inf inf

0   1   2   3   inf inf
0   2   3   39  inf inf
0   12  22  23  inf inf

0   1   2   3   4   inf
0   2   3   4   47  inf
0   12  12  23  24  inf

0   1   2   3   4   5  
0   2   3   4   5   48  
0   12  12  12  24  25 

0   1   2   3   4   5  
0   2   3   4   5   6   
0   12  12  12  6   25 

0   1   2   3   4   5
0   2   3   4   5   6
0   12  12  7   6   7

0   1   2   3   4   5
0   2   3   4   5   6
0   12  8   7   6   7

0   1   2   3   4   5
0   2   3   4   5   6
0   9   8   7   6   7
```

No further changes will take place in the upper-left corner.  You can see that it is slowly discovering the minimum cost to reach each cell.

Comment: Do you know a way to characterize the number of steps that this will take until convergence?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't always start from `[0, 0]` though. Should we run it for all rows of column `0th` and compares them?

Comment: @Chan: I didn't read your question closely enough.  I've updated my answer.  It isn't necessary to run the algorithm multiple times, you just need a different start state.